# Как сложить результаты двух таблиц?

Tags: delphi

Есть две таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE [ostatky] (
  [id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  [d] INTEGER, 
  [m] VARCHAR(20), 
  [y] INTEGER, 
  [point] VARCHAR(80), 
  [predprijatie] VARCHAR(80), 
  [ostatok] CURRENCY);

CREATE TABLE [main] (
  [id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  [d] INTEGER, 
  [m] VARCHAR(20), 
  [y] INTEGER, 
  [point] VARCHAR(80), 
  [predprijatie] VARCHAR(80), 
  [prihod] CURRENCY, 
  [rashod] CURRENCY);
```

Надо получить результат сложения `[ostatok]` первой таблицы и `[prihod]` второй таблицы и от этого отнять `[rashod]` второй таблицы...ну...как то так `SUM(ostatok)+SUM(prihod)-SUM(rashod)`. Как это сделать?

Comment: я пробовал делать так:
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(O.ostatok), SUM(M.prihod), SUM(M.rashod)
FROM ostatky O, main M
Но так он считает неправильно. В таблице "Остатки" в сумме должно получаться 800, а получается 1600. Это происходит тогда, когда я в запрос добавляю вторую таблицу...почему так...не понимаю...

Comment: Потому, что вы должны еще дописать выборку, тем самым соединив две таблицы. Не знаю, как это выглядит в той БД, что вы используете, но в MySQL это бы выглядело так:

    SELECT DISTINCT SUM(O.ostatok), SUM(M.prihod), SUM(M.rashod) FROM ostatky O, main M WHERE O.id = M.id

Еще не понимаю, зачем вы здесь используете DISTINCT. Вы уверены, что он нужен?

Comment: ну...я делал практически так же... DISTINCT, пожалуй, не нужен... но, таблицы ни как не связаны..., так что WHERE O.id = M.id, тут не прокатит... в таблице [ostatky] есть 4 записи, каждая 200, т.е. в итоге должно получиться 800, а результат запроса 1600...
При чем, неправильный результат получается в случае, если в запросе участвуют обе таблицы, если одна таблица, то результат верный

Comment: Вытягивайте тогда из одной таблицы необходимые суммы, затем из другой и программно считайте разницу. Хотя, может, есть и более логичный ход для вашей БД.

Comment: не...надо одним запросом

Comment: надо было так:
SELECT SUM(ostatky.ostatok) + (SELECT SUM(prihod) - SUM(rashod) FROM main) 
FROM ostatky
Так все верно считается

Comment: Очень хочется сказать что-нибудь неприличное по поводу Вашей схемы, в которой нарушены ВСЕ правила создания РБД. Полагаю, что это Ваше затруднение - не последнее. Послушайте совета: приведите схему в порядок.